# What can I do about Google Cloud Pub/Sub message size limit?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

So, the message size limit is 10Mb.

I've been using Pub/Sub as both an input and output for data pipelines because of its low latency. The assumption here is that the Pub/Sub is the fastest mechanism on Google Cloud to pull data into a Compute Engine instance and push it out of this instance one (or few) data point at a time (not in batch manner). Then a Cloud Function with pub/sub push subscription writes the output to BigQuery.

99% of the data I process does not exceed 1MB. But there are some outliers with over 10MB size.

What can I do about it? Leverage some kind of compression? Write output to Cloud Storage instead of Pub/Sub? Maybe to a persistent SSD? I want to make sure that my compute instances are doing their job digesting one data point at a time and spitting the output with minimal time spent on pulling and pushing data and max time spent on transforming it.

Comment: If your messages are larger than a few KB, then you are designing incorrectly. Post a message with a link to the data stored on Cloud Storage. PubSub is a messaging system and not a data transfer system. The performance will improve and costs will decrease. See @guillaume-blaquiere correct answer. Do not use compression unless you have lots of CPU cycles to waste.

Comment: As I said, over 99% of the messages are less than 1MB. Adding GCS to this mix introduces a lot of unnecessary complexity and delays. 99 percentile of my data processing costs 98% for computing, 0.5% for Cloud Pub/Sub and 1.5% for other stuff. Making my Compute Instances wait for the GCS uploads/downloads costs way more. Do you still think that my design is incorrect?

Comment: The corner cases determine if a design is correct. You answered your own question.

Answer (score 11):

The safest and the most scalable way is to save the data to Cloud Storage and to only publish the file reference in PubSub, not the content. It's also the most cost efficient way.

You can also imagine compressing the data, if they are compressible. It could be fastest than using Cloud Storage, but not as scalable.

Comment: Does Pub/Sub have built-in compression API? Or I suppose to compress and decompress it with custom code?

Comment: No, it's custom code. Either custom code to compress/decompress message content, or custom code to write/read to/from Cloud Storage. In both case you have to write code. The lowest latency is not to use GCS.